# Flask python app crashes on heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask

I tried pushing my code directly to Heroku for hosting but I got so many errors. Now, what I did was host the code on Github, and then link the git repo with Heroku. Now, the Heroku app was created successfully but now it does not run as it crashes with an error code of H10 and status 503. My app.py code is;

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## From Heroku

```
Application Logs:

2017-06-07T04:06:26.163984+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2017-06-07T04:32:14.975648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 
to starting
2017-06-07T04:32:25.466677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `gunicorn malicha:app --log-file=-`
2017-06-07T04:32:27.733743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 
127
2017-06-07T04:32:27.646433+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not 
found
2017-06-07T04:32:27.750144+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2017-06-07T05:23:25.211376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 
to starting
2017-06-07T05:23:36.977579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `gunicorn malicha:app --log-file=-`
2017-06-07T05:23:39.121911+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not 
found
2017-06-07T05:23:39.208060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2017-06-07T05:23:39.193064+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 207
```

## My requirements.txt

```
AppInst==2.1.5
Flask==0.12.2
Jinja2==2.9.6
MarkupSafe==1.0
Pillow==4.0.0
PyYAML==3.11
Pygments==2.1.3
Werkzeug==0.12.2
appdirs==1.4.3
apptools==4.4.0
argparse==1.4.0
attrs==15.2.0
backports-abc==0.5  
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0   
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
bleach==1.5.0
boto==2.40.0
certifi==2017.4.17
chardet==3.0.3
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
colorthief==0.2.1
configobj==5.0.6
configparser==3.5.0
cycler==0.10.0  
decorator==4.0.9
dlib==19.4.0
docutils==0.13.1
ecdsa==0.13
encore==0.7.0
enstaller==4.8.12
entrypoints==0.2.2
enum34==1.1.6
envisage==4.6.0
esky==0.9.8  
feedparser==5.2.1
flake8==3.3.0
futures==3.0.3
gnureadline==6.3.3
gunicorn==19.7.1
hatcher==0.10.4
html5lib==0.999
humanize==0.5.1
idna==2.5
imutils==0.4.3
ipykernel==4.5.2
ipython==4.0.0
ipython-genutils==0.1.0 
ipywidgets==6.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.10.2
jsonify==0.5
jsonschema==2.6.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.0.0   
jupyter-console==5.1.0  
jupyter-core==4.3.0 
keyring==10.3.3
lxml==3.8.0
matplotlib==2.0.2
mccabe==0.6.1
memory-profiler==0.43   
mistune==0.7.4
mpmath==0.19
nbconvert==5.2.1
nbformat==4.3.0
nose==1.3.7
notebook==4.4.1
numpy==1.12.1
okonomiyaki==0.16.10
olefile==0.44
opencv-python==3.2.0.7 
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.20.2
pandocfilters==1.4.1
path.py==10.3.1
pathlib2==2.2.1
pbr==3.0.1
pep8==1.7.0
pexpect==4.2.1
pickleshare==0.7.4
pip==9.0.1
plotly==2.0.9
ply==3.10
prompt-toolkit==1.0.13  
psutil==5.2.2
psycopg2==2.7.1
ptyprocess==0.5.1
pyasn1==0.2.3
pycodestyle==2.3.1
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyface==5.1.0
pyflakes==1.5.0
pyglet==1.1.4
pymongo==3.4.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
pyzmq==16.0.2
qtconsole==4.3.0
requests==2.17.3
rsa==3.4.2
scipy==0.19.0 
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
stevedore==1.23.0
sympy==1.0
tabulate==0.7.7
terminado==0.6
testpath==0.3.1
tornado==4.5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
traits==4.6.0
traits-enaml==0.2.1
traitsui==5.1.0
tzlocal==1.4
urllib3==1.21.1
virtualenv==15.1.0
wcwidth==0.1.7
cmake==0.7.1
```

## My Procfile

```
    web: gunicorn malicha:app --log-file=-
```

## Build Log

the section of the build log after

```html
-----> Found requirements.txt, installing dependencies using pip
DEPRECATION: --allow-all-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.
Collecting AppInst==2.1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading AppInst-2.1.5.tar.gz
Collecting Flask==0.12.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
Collecting Jinja2==2.9.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading Jinja2-2.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe==1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting Pillow==4.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading Pillow-4.0.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.6MB)
Collecting PyYAML==3.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading PyYAML-3.11.zip (371kB)
Collecting Pygments==2.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading Pygments-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (755kB)
Collecting Werkzeug==0.12.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading Werkzeug-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (312kB)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs==1.4.3 in ./.heroku/vendor/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
Collecting apptools==4.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
  Downloading apptools-4.4.0.zip (490kB)
Collecting argparse==1.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
  Downloading argparse-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting attrs==15.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
  Downloading attrs-15.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports-abc==0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
  Downloading backports_abc-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
  Downloading backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py2-none-any.whl (81kB)
Collecting bleach==1.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
  Downloading bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting boto==2.40.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
  Downloading boto-2.40.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Collecting certifi==2017.4.17 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
  Downloading certifi-2017.4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (375kB)
Collecting chardet==3.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
  Downloading chardet-3.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
Collecting click==6.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
  Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
Collecting colorama==0.3.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
  Downloading colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorthief==0.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
  Downloading colorthief-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting configobj==5.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
  Downloading configobj-5.0.6.tar.gz
Collecting configparser==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
  Downloading configparser-3.5.0.tar.gz
Collecting cycler==0.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
  Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator==4.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
  Downloading decorator-4.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: dlib==19.4.0 in ./.heroku/vendor/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 27))
Collecting docutils==0.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
  Downloading docutils-0.13.1-py2-none-any.whl (537kB)
Collecting ecdsa==0.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))
  Downloading ecdsa-0.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86kB)
Collecting encore==0.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
  Downloading encore-0.7.0.tar.gz (122kB)
Collecting enstaller==4.8.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))
  Downloading enstaller-4.8.12.tar.gz (905kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-PRtgXg/enstaller/setup.py", line 146, in <module>
        write_version_py()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-PRtgXg/enstaller/setup.py", line 88, in write_version_py
        raise ImportError("Unable to import git_revision. Try removing "
    ImportError: Unable to import git_revision. Try removing enstaller/_version.py and the build directory before building.
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PRtgXg/enstaller/
-----> Creating environment variables.
-----> Buildpack installed.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 176.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v26
       https://malicha.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

## error while building

```
on inspecting the build log, I discovered an error while building :  Downloading enstaller-4.8.12.tar.gz (905kB)
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-PRtgXg/enstaller/setup.py", line 146, in <module>
    write_version_py()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-PRtgXg/enstaller/setup.py", line 88, in write_version_py
    raise ImportError("Unable to import git_revision. Try removing "
ImportError: Unable to import git_revision. Try removing enstaller/_version.py and the build directory before building.

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-PRtgXg/enstaller/

Comment: What's the error in the log?

Comment: What is your Procfile ? And do you have requirements.txt file ?

Comment: My guess is that your `Procfile` tries to run `gunicorn`, but `gunicorn` is missing in your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Hi Raja, I renamed the app.py file to malicha.py in my project folder as you instructed at stack exchange, yet I get an "Application error " when I run the app

Comment: Hi Smarx, gunicorn is included in my requirements.txt file

Comment: Well, the log seems to indicate that `gunicorn` is not installed. I would double check your `requirements.txt`, make sure it's been committed and pushed, and check any logs you have during deployment to see if installation somehow didn't happen.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I used this buildpack : https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku14-buildpack-python-opencv-dlib.git

Comment: When you deploy, do you see "Found requirements.txt, installing dependencies using pip"? Maybe just paste the full output during deployment?

Comment: I tried posting the full output it exceeds stack overflow's 30k characters input, it contains ~ 280K characters

Comment: yes Smarx, it does contain " Found requirements.txt, installing dependencies using pip"

Comment: on inspecting the build log, I discovered an error while building, but I don't really know how to resolve this.

Comment: Do you know if you truly need `enstaller`? Your `requirements.txt` is huge and includes things like `virtualenv` (which surely your app doesn't need). Certainly for your hello world app, all you need is Flask and Gunicorn, so try removing everything else from `requirements.txt` as a start?

Comment: Thanks smarx, I finally fixed it, after spending half of my day on this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply editing my Procfile from

```
web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-
```

to

```
web: gunicorn src.app:app --log-file=-
```

Comment: Did you add src.app because app was inside src folder?